# Oracle SQL Developer returning different datetime results than OdbcDataAdapter

Tags: oracle, date, odbc

We have a C# job that is querying an Oracle database (version 12.1.0.2) on the OdbcDataAdapter object like this:

```
            using (OdbcConnection OdbcConn = source.GetOdbcConnection())
            {
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, OdbcConn);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                using (OdbcDataAdapter dAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    dAdapter.Fill(fileLoaded);
                }
            }
```

The query contains this in the select:

,TO_CHAR(DEL_DTTM, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') "Delivery Time2"

When the above code runs, '2018-10-21 02:24:00' is returned. However, when the same query is run in SQL Developer (Oracle query editor), we are getting '2018-10-21 03:24:00'.

(Adding more details)
This column is actually a 'DATE' type. And come to find out, this is actually stored as '2018-10-21 07:24:00', and is being manipulated via a view by this function:

,to_char(CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(OB_DEL_BIRTH_DTTM AS TIMESTAMP),'GMT') AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE) AS DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as DEL_DTTM

I'm in the America/New_York timezone, so what I think is happening is this conversion is applying 'todays date' to the localization from the ODBC connection, but 'today' is GMT -5:00, whereas the date being compared is during Daylight Savings, so should be -4:00.

(More Details)
So when I run the 'select sessiontimezone from dual' in SQL Developer, I get 'America/New_York', but then through C#/ODBC I get -5:00. If I run 'select TZ_OFFSET(sessiontimezone) from dual' through both I get -5:00.

Any ideas my friends?

Comment: What is the column datatype (and what are the others that don't see this behaviour)? I imagine it's a timestamp with local time zone, so different sessions (correctly) see different local times?

Comment: Well, It seems that C#OdbcDataAdapter is using different sessiontimezone than SQL-Developer. Please run `SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL` in SQL-Developer and in your C# code using OdbcDataAdapter, and append results of this query to the question.